# Django - 'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

Getting an error for `AnonymousUser`. What I code here is only for the authenticated user. But an unauthenticated user cannot add a product.

I want to work it like, if user comes to the website and clicks on add to cart the product should be added to the cart. Then when he tries to sign in. The products should be in the  cart.

`cart models.py`

```
# Create your models here.
class CartItem(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    item_total = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.quantity} of {self.item.name}"

def pre_save_cart_item(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    instance.item_total = instance.quantity * instance.item.price

pre_save.connect(pre_save_cart_item, sender=CartItem)

class Cart(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='cart')

    items = models.ManyToManyField(CartItem)
    number_of_items = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    total = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    purchased = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"User: {self.owner}, items in cart {self.number_of_items}"

def m2m_save_cart(sender, action, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if action == 'post_add' or action == 'post_remove' or action == 'post_clear':
        instance.number_of_items = instance.items.count()
        items = instance.items.all()
        instance.total = 0
        for x in items:
            instance.total += x.item_total
        instance.save()


m2m_changed.connect(m2m_save_cart, sender=Cart.items.through)
```

`cart views.py`

```
# Create your views here.

def add_to_cart(request, slug):
    item = get_object_or_404(Product, slug=slug)

    cart_item, created = CartItem.objects.get_or_create(
        item=item,
        owner = request.user,
    )
    cart_qs = Cart.objects.filter(owner=request.user, purchased=False)
    if cart_qs.exists():
        cart = cart_qs[0]
        if cart.items.filter(item__slug=item.slug).exists():
            cart_item.quantity += 1
            cart_item.save()
            return redirect('products:product-list')
        else:
            cart.items.add(cart_item)
            return redirect('products:product-list')
    else:
        cart = Cart.objects.create(
            owner=request.user
        )
        cart.items.add(cart_item)
        return redirect('products:product-list')

def remove_from_cart(request, slug):
    item = get_object_or_404(Product, slug=slug)
    cart_qs = Cart.objects.filter(owner=request.user, purchased=False)
    if cart_qs.exists():
        cart = cart_qs[0]
        print('cart_qs exists')
        if cart.items.filter(item__slug=item.slug).exists():
            print('item exists in cart')
            cart_item = CartItem.objects.filter(
                item = item,
                owner = request.user,
            )[0]
            cart.items.remove(cart_item)
            print('removed from cart')
            cart_item.delete()
            return redirect('products:product-list')
        else:
            print('item not in cart')
            return redirect('')
    else:
        return redirect('')
        print('no cart_qs')

def remove_single_item_from_cart(request, slug):
    item = get_object_or_404(Product, slug=slug)
    cart_qs = Cart.objects.filter(owner=request.user, purchased=False)
    if cart_qs.exists():
        cart = cart_qs[0]
        print('cart_qs exists')
        if cart.items.filter(item__slug=item.slug).exists():
            print('item exists in cart')
            cart_item = CartItem.objects.filter(
                item = item,
                owner = request.user,
            )[0]
            if cart_item.quantity > 1:
                cart_item.quantity -= 1
                cart_item.save()
                print(item,'quantity decreased')
            else:
                cart.items.remove(cart_item)
                print('removed from cart')
            return redirect('products:product-list')
        else:
            print('item not in cart')
            return redirect('products:product-list')
    else:
        print('no cart_qs')
        return redirect('products:product-list')
```

`TRACEBACK`

Internal Server Error: /cart/cart/add-to-cart/test-product-1
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\debop\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\MONDAY\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\debop\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\MONDAY\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\debop\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\MONDAY\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\debop\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\MONDAY\src\carts\views.py", line 14, in add_to_cart
    cart_item, created = CartItem.objects.get_or_create(

File "C:\Users\debop\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\MONDAY\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\debop\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\MONDAY\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 559, in get_or_create
    return self.get(**kwargs), False

File "C:\Users\debop\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\MONDAY\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 404, in get
    clone = self._chain() if self.query.combinator else self.filter(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\debop\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\MONDAY\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 904, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\debop\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\MONDAY\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 923, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))

File "C:\Users\debop\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\MONDAY\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1350, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)

File "C:\Users\debop\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\MONDAY\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1377, in _add_q
    child_clause, needed_inner = self.build_filter(

File "C:\Users\debop\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\MONDAY\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1284, in build_filter
    self.check_related_objects(join_info.final_field, value, join_info.opts)

File "C:\Users\debop\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\MONDAY\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1124, in check_related_objects
    for v in value:

File "C:\Users\debop\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\MONDAY\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 225, in inner
    return func(self._wrapped, *args)

TypeError: 'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable
[06/Apr/2020 16:09:07] "GET /cart/cart/add-to-cart/test-product-1 HTTP/1.1" 500 
116667

Comment: where's the error trace?

Comment: @dirkgroten Added it.

Comment: Here's the error: `File "C:\Users\debop\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\MONDAY\src\carts\views.py", line 14, in add_to_cart cart_item, created = CartItem.objects.get_or_create(` so tell us which is line 14 of your `views.py`.

Comment: You need to check if `request.user` is `anonymous` or not, if it is, then use `None` instead of `request.user`.

Comment: @dirkgroten Okay that make sense. But can you help with something more. If I set `None` here then when a user log backs in before going for checkout how will I save the user to that cart instance? Until and unless the order is complete, it should be available to that user.

Comment: Whatever is in the session will still be in the session after the user logs in, even though the session id changes. So if you store the cart id in your session, it'll always be there.

Comment: @dirkgroten What if the user logs out of the session adds some more product and logs back in. Will the cart still hold the previous product?

Comment: Logout normally flushes the session, so no, in that case it won't work because he'll be using a fresh cart after having logged out. That's why generally, before saving a cart, there's a check whether the user already has a cart in which case they are merged.

Comment: @dirkgroten When should I check this  condition? after the user adds the product to the cart and then when he tries to log in, that's when it should check?

Comment: Always check in `add_to_cart()`. Well actually in `add_to_cart()` you're already checking. But you're not using the cart in the session right now. So when you add the cart id to the session and find 2 carts (one for the user and one for the session) you should merge.